# Is there anything in Buddhism analogous to the Christian Eucharist?

Tags: philosophy, christianity

I hope to have a go at reading a little about the Eucharist. Because my religious sympathies largely lie with Buddhism, I thought it'd be good to know of anything comparative therein.

Comment: [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eucharist) seems like a good introduction to the Eucharist. I suspect that this question isn't on-topic: because you're trying to understand the Christian Eucharist (about which you've read very little so far), not asking a question to try to understand Buddhism.

Comment: hi @ChrisW thanks for the reply but of course i don't think it's off topic, as e.g. i do believe i'm asking a question to try and understand buddhism

Comment: If you haven't yet read even a little about the Eucharist, then how can telling you "this practice in Buddhism reminds me of the Eucharist" help you understand Buddhism? IMO the Eucharist isn't mainly about Transubstantiation (except perhaps as a reminder that the human body must eat, lives and will die) but is more about a) remembrance or mindfulness of Jesus (which is maybe like going to the Buddha for refuge) b) about gratitude or thanksgiving, e.g. for liberation (which might exist in Buddhism somehow but not exactly the same because there is no God to thank) ...

Comment: ... c) eating, which is also a practice in Buddhism, e.g. [Three Buddhist Verses to Chant Before Eating](http://buddhism.about.com/od/becomingabuddhist/a/mealchants.htm) d) gathering into a community. However I don't see how to answer this question without it being more about the Eucharist than about Buddhism. Can you explain how to do that, and/or edit the question to make so that it doesn't seem to be asking "How could you explain the Christian Eucharist, to a Buddhist, using Buddhist practices and beliefs as an analogy"?

Comment: One analogy is that, whereas Christ said "This is my body" during their last supper while giving thanks and breaking bread, during the Buddha's last night he said that the Dhamma would be his body.

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks if there is "anything analogous." In my experience, the tsok feast fits that bill. Sharing the food gifts that were offered leads to a similar virtuous and calm mind, with feelings of gratitude and appreciation of community.

Comment: Hi Brian and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have some [guidelines](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?cb=1) for new user that you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

[*Chod practice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%B6d). 
It is a practice of offering one's body and blood.

Answer (score 0):

Christ spoke in parables so it is difficult do say anything definite but it looks like it possibly could be  a mindfulness ritual to remember the teachings of Christ and the potential of Christ is inside everyone... like every one is a Buddha.